# Using AWS S3 Object tags to breakdown costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cost-explorer

In our s3 setup we have a couple of buckets that have files for only one project each, but some buckets that contain files for multiple projects. I recently tagged a bunch of objects with a "Project" tag (e.g. Project:Foo) and also a bucket with a "Project" tag (e.g. Project:Bar). I have also enabled the "Project" tag as a cost allocation tag.

When I look in Cost Explorer and try and filter/get a break down by the "Project" tag, only the "Bar" tag, which is assigned to a bucket shows up. None of the "Foo" tags which are on objects appear.

Is there a way to use the tags on S3 objects to group costs, rather than just the tags of buckets?

I know the obvious answer would be to move everything to seperate buckets but that's just not practical for us due to the amount of data stored and it would also necessitate a substantial re-design of several of our workflows.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CostAllocTagging.html), cost allocation tags can only be used to label buckets.

Comment: Yes I saw that. I was hoping that someone had a better/different way. Currently it's looking like the best option will be to get an inventory of each bucket and then calculate the costs per tag from that. Not ideal but it can be automated at least

Comment: Spend a lot of time to automate the report, just split the bucket.